# Apple's Map Program Crashes repeatedly and reliably whenever a zoom is attempted

Tags: mac, crash, maps

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I am stumped.

Here is the crash report (with the binary images removed):

```
Process:               Maps [999]
Path:                  /Applications/Maps.app/Contents/MacOS/Maps
Identifier:            com.apple.Maps
Version:               2.0 (1906.2.15.2)
Build Info:            Maps-1906002015002000~5
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Maps [999]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-10-02 07:21:41.274 -0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.1 (15B22c)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        B70F61B6-D310-B587-35CB-FDC2E562FD01


Time Awake Since Boot: 510 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x18:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000103dce000-0000000103fcc000 [ 2040K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Maps.app/Contents/MacOS/Maps

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: raise


Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
12.237846    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793a11 [0x7ffa34bc2600] Releasing session
12.239115    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879611c [0x7ffa34bc2600] Decoding completed without errors
12.243006    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff887940fc [UNSUP] Options: 2147103932x33554432 [02000000,FFFF0000] FFFFFFFF
12.243006    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793fae [0x7ffa34bc2600] Decoding: C0 0x02000200 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 45030
12.243037    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879305e [0x7ffa34bc2600] Created session
12.243838    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793a11 [0x7ffa342e5000] Releasing session
12.244076    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879611c [0x7ffa342e5000] Decoding completed without errors
12.246771    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff887940fc [0x7ffa342e5000] Options: 512x512 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
12.246771    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793fae [0x7ffa342e5000] Decoding: C0 0x02000200 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 47969
12.246909    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879305e [0x7ffa342e5000] Created session
12.270086    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793a11 [0x7ffa33dac400] Releasing session
12.270966    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879611c [0x7ffa33dac400] Decoding completed without errors
12.276004    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff887940fc [0x7ffa33dac400] Options: 512x512 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
12.276004    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793fae [0x7ffa33dac400] Decoding: C0 0x02000200 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 38706
12.276508    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879305e [0x7ffa33dac400] Created session
12.277780    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793a11 [0x7ffa35464400] Releasing session
12.278343    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793a11 [0x7ffa33dac400] Releasing session
12.280256    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879611c [0x7ffa35464400] Decoding completed without errors
12.280417    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879611c [0x7ffa33dac400] Decoding completed without errors
12.293932    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff887940fc [0x7ffa35464400] Options: 512x512 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
12.293932    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793fae [0x7ffa35464400] Decoding: C0 0x02000200 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 47912
12.293960    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793a11 [0x7ffa35454c00] Releasing session
12.296228    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879611c [0x7ffa35454c00] Decoding completed without errors
12.296535    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879305e [0x7ffa35464400] Created session
12.306215    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff887940fc [0x7ffa35454c00] Options: 512x512 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
12.306215    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793fae [0x7ffa35454c00] Decoding: C0 0x02000200 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 42887
12.306594    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879305e [0x7ffa35454c00] Created session
12.306667    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff887940fc [0x7ffa33dac400] Options: 512x512 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060
12.306667    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793fae [0x7ffa33dac400] Decoding: C0 0x02000200 0x0000304A 0x22111100 0x00000000 46188
12.307573    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879305e [0x7ffa33dac400] Created session
12.348568    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793a11 [0x7ffa354d5200] Releasing session
12.351225    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879611c [0x7ffa354d5200] Decoding completed without errors
12.352702    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff88793a11 [0x7ffa34bb2c00] Releasing session
12.353156    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff8879611c [0x7ffa34bb2c00] Decoding completed without errors
12.353797    AppleJPEG                  0x00007fff887940fc [0x7ffa354d5200] Options: 512x512 [FFFFFFFF,FFFFFFFF] 00025060

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff95e45d5d objc_msgSend + 29
1   com.apple.MapKit                0x00007fff89ff743d -[MKZoomSegmentedControl mouseDown:] + 184
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff899cc42d -[NSWindow _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6322
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff899cd411 -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 212
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89412b8d -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 517
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff89392b27 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2540
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff891f9d9a -[NSApplication run] + 796
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff891c2fbe NSApplicationMain + 1176
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff92e0d5ad start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1a078a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1a10a2 kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8cebc11d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8cebbd85 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1a078a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1a078a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1a078a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1a078a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1a078a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d1a078a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d58c _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b375 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:: NetworkLoad
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d19ac96 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d19a0d7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff955e4054 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff955e351c __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff955e2d68 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.GeoServices           0x00007fff915cd42e _runNetworkThread + 445
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d9b1 _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d92e _pthread_start + 168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b385 thread_start + 13

Thread 10:: CVDisplayLink
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d19ff5e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060e73d _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff88414f76 CVDisplayLink::runIOThread() + 676
3   com.apple.CoreVideo             0x00007fff884149a9 startIOThread(void*) + 147
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d9b1 _pthread_body + 131
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d92e _pthread_start + 168
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b385 thread_start + 13

Thread 11:: /loading/processingjobmanager/workers/worker0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d19ff5e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060e73d _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff909c39f3 karo::JobManager::onWorkerStepDone(karo::Worker*) + 819
3   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff9087e45b karo::Worker::threadMain() + 59
4   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff9090c589 karo::Thread::callback(void*) + 985
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d9b1 _pthread_body + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d92e _pthread_start + 168
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b385 thread_start + 13

Thread 12:: /loading/processingjobmanager/workers/worker1
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d19ff5e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060e73d _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff909c39f3 karo::JobManager::onWorkerStepDone(karo::Worker*) + 819
3   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff9087e45b karo::Worker::threadMain() + 59
4   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff9090c589 karo::Thread::callback(void*) + 985
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d9b1 _pthread_body + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d92e _pthread_start + 168
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b385 thread_start + 13

Thread 13:: /loading/processingjobmanager/workers/worker2
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d19ff5e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060e73d _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff909c39f3 karo::JobManager::onWorkerStepDone(karo::Worker*) + 819
3   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff9087e45b karo::Worker::threadMain() + 59
4   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff9090c589 karo::Thread::callback(void*) + 985
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d9b1 _pthread_body + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d92e _pthread_start + 168
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b385 thread_start + 13

Thread 14:: /loading/genericjobmanager/workers/worker0
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d19ff5e __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060e73d _pthread_cond_wait + 767
2   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff909c39f3 karo::JobManager::onWorkerStepDone(karo::Worker*) + 819
3   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff9087e45b karo::Worker::threadMain() + 59
4   com.apple.VectorKit             0x00007fff9090c589 karo::Thread::callback(void*) + 985
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d9b1 _pthread_body + 131
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d92e _pthread_start + 168
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b385 thread_start + 13

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d19acea semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8cec1c1f _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 149
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8cebbcd3 _dispatch_worker_thread + 148
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d9b1 _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d92e _pthread_start + 168
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b385 thread_start + 13

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d19acea semaphore_timedwait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8cec1c1f _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 149
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8cebbcd3 _dispatch_worker_thread + 148
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d9b1 _pthread_body + 131
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d92e _pthread_start + 168
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b385 thread_start + 13

Thread 17:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d19ac96 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8d19a0d7 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff955e4054 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff955e351c __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff955e2d68 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8935bd49 _NSEventThread + 149
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d9b1 _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060d92e _pthread_start + 168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff9060b385 thread_start + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x021dffff783cfccd  rbx: 0x00007fff95e45d40  rcx: 0x0100000000000000  rdx: 0x0040000000000000
  rdi: 0x00007ffa3373f5b0  rsi: 0x00007fff959bd5da  rbp: 0x00007fff5be317f0  rsp: 0x00007fff5be31738
   r8: 0x0000000000000001   r9: 0x0000000000000002  r10: 0x00007fff959bd5da  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x00007ffa3373f5b0  r13: 0x00007fff89bec919  r14: 0x00007fff89c07570  r15: 0x00007ffa335e74f0
  rip: 0x00007fff95e45d5d  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x0000000000000018

Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       [REDACTED BECAUSE BODY LIMIT IS 30,000 characters here]

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 3
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 9194
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=314.3M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=314.3M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=196.0M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=196.0M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
ATS (font support)                32.2M        9 
ATS (font support) (reserved)        4K        2         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Accelerate.framework               256K        3 
Activity Tracing                  2048K        2 
CG backing stores                  688K        5 
CG image                           328K       18 
CG raster data                      24K        2 
CG shared images                   336K       10 
CoreAnimation                      952K       47 
CoreData Object IDs               4100K        3 
CoreUI image data                  292K       14 
CoreUI image file                  256K        6 
Dispatch continuations            8192K        2 
Foundation                         492K       12 
IOKit                             15.5M        2 
Image IO                             4K        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        3 
MALLOC                            93.6M       63 
MALLOC guard page                   32K        7 
Memory Tag 242                      12K        2 
Memory Tag 251                      76K        3 
OpenCL                               8K        2 
OpenGL GLSL                        256K        4 
Process Corpse Info               2048K        2 
SQLite page cache                  768K        4 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       19 
Stack                             16.2M       19 
VM_ALLOCATE                       18.2M       21 
__DATA                            31.8M      301 
__GLSLBUILTINS                    2588K        2 
__IMAGE                            528K        2 
__LINKEDIT                        90.7M       18 
__TEXT                           223.6M      307 
__UNICODE                          552K        2 
mapped file                       49.2M       22 
shared memory                     16.3M        8 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            667.6M      914 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space   667.5M      914
```

Or view the complete `.crash` file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3skvousxryckemk/Maps_2015-10-02-072149_Charles-Air-8.crash?dl=0

Comment: Have you done anything to your fonts? I have a brand new 15 inch Retina that is crashing every time I try to zoom. I can change to different views (satellite/map/transit) and pan around, but anything involving zoom or 3D crashes. The only thing unusual I have done is manually add custom fonts to my Library folder. I'm curious if you've done the same.

Comment: Ugh. You are a complete lifesaver, Steven. My system fonts were fine, but I use FontAgent Pro to handle fonts too. And one of them, I think Bodoni, was the problem. Thanks so much! I had completely given up hope!