# What caused my Mac to crash?

Tags: macos, crash, catalina, kernel-panic

I have two files from the crash. First is the report that is sent to Apple. And the second one is from the Console app crash report.

It's a new Mac and it's been running for only a couple days. That's the reason for the concern. Am I right by saying that Spotlight caused the crash? It says corespotlightd below.

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f9979dad5): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from com.apple.WindowServer in 120 seconds
service: com.apple.logd, total successful checkins since wake (130 seconds ago): 14, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago
service: com.apple.WindowServer, total successful checkins since wake (130 seconds ago): 2, last successful checkin: 120 seconds ago

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9218893820 : 0xffffff8018d3bb1b 
0xffffff9218893870 : 0xffffff8018e733e5 
0xffffff92188938b0 : 0xffffff8018e64e5e 
0xffffff9218893900 : 0xffffff8018ce2a40 
0xffffff9218893920 : 0xffffff8018d3b207 
0xffffff9218893a20 : 0xffffff8018d3b5eb 
0xffffff9218893a70 : 0xffffff80194d2575 
0xffffff9218893ae0 : 0xffffff7f9979dad5 
0xffffff9218893af0 : 0xffffff7f9979d7e6 
0xffffff9218893b10 : 0xffffff8019466fcb 
0xffffff9218893b60 : 0xffffff8019470083 
0xffffff9218893ca0 : 0xffffff8018e22c22 
0xffffff9218893db0 : 0xffffff8018d41998 
0xffffff9218893e10 : 0xffffff8018d18625 
0xffffff9218893e70 : 0xffffff8018d2f0d5 
0xffffff9218893f00 : 0xffffff8018e4b485 
0xffffff9218893fa0 : 0xffffff8018ce3226 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[EFAA17B9-A62C-30B7-9602-0BB5282EDDD6]@0xffffff7f9979c000->0xffffff7f997a4fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: watchdogd
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19C57

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: C3E7E405-C692-356B-88D3-C30041FD1E72
Kernel slide:     0x0000000018a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8018c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8018b00000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 13384514045597
last loaded kext at 11826213638254: >usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f9cc92000, size 45056)
last unloaded kext at 12105008273609: >!UAudio  320.49 (addr 0xffffff7fa0053000, size 434176)
loaded kexts:
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    3.0.4
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.4
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.21
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.21
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.2f4
>pmtelemetry    1
>AGPM   111.4.1
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AGDCBacklightControl   4.5.21
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.3
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.60
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3420.1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.60
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.3
>!AMuxControl2  4.5.21
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.422
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.61.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  3.0.4
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  4.5.21
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 3.0.4
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AHS!BDriver   3420.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.2f4
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.2f4
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.2f4
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.8
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!AGraphicsControl  4.5.21
>!AActuatorDriver   3420.2
>!AMultitouchDriver 3420.2
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3420.4
|IONDRVSupport  569.3
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.4
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.21
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   569.3
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    800.14
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.ethernet.asix  5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.1
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.7
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.60.3
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   800.14
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.2f4
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.2f4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

And (part of) the Console app crash report:

```
Process:               corespotlightd [1028]
Path:                  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/corespotlightd
Identifier:            corespotlightd
Version:               2074.4
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           corespotlightd [1028]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-12-28 21:21:20.141 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B2093)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     4.1 (17P1583)
Anonymous UUID:        465F0761-80AE-46C2-AEDA-2E001E66AC89

Sleep/Wake UUID:       4CD66331-6E1A-416B-918E-5C702E7F7B1B

Time Awake Since Boot: 4100 seconds
Time Since Wake:       300 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        14  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [1028]

Application Specific Information:
dyld3 mode
[0x7000094e4000] Error unliking store.updates: 2
[0x1047f9dc0] Failed to get kMDStoreAccumulatedCounts
[0x1047f9dc0] Failed to get kMDStoreAccumulatedSizes
[0x1047f9dc0] open meta info error -1
Initializing
Kernel bug: The kernel cannot allocate memory needed for the pseudo-receive.

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a599166 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a5996cc mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3305c260 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 322
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3305b7e6 __CFRunLoopRun + 1705
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff3305aec8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 503
5   corespotlightd                  0x0000000103ee1cba 0x103ed2000 + 64698
6   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6a4502e5 start + 1

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a599166 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a5996cc mach_msg + 60
2   com.apple.spotlight.index       0x00007fff61c7cbef _handleExceptions + 120
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a660d36 _pthread_start + 125
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d58f thread_start + 15

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff6a6ba615 _xpc_connection_release_message.cold.2 + 14
1   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff6a69d61d _xpc_connection_release_message + 108
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff6a69cda6 _xpc_connection_handle_event_inline + 71
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a413a29 _dispatch_mach_handle_or_push_received_msg + 100
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a417f3c _dispatch_mach_msg_send + 322
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a417a2e _dispatch_mach_send_drain + 413
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a4142ca _dispatch_mach_notification_merge_evt + 36
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a41cb75 _dispatch_mach_notify_merge + 275
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a41cbee _dispatch_mach_notify_send_possible + 18
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a42acb4 _Xmach_notify_send_possible + 33
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a42aebe libdispatch_internal_protocol_server + 81
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a41ccb1 _dispatch_mach_notification_merge_msg + 61
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a41b56e _dispatch_event_loop_merge + 119
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a40f2b2 _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 850
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d763 _pthread_wqthread + 362
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d57b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 17:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.spotlight.SearchAgent.queue
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6a59d032 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6a5200fa nanosleep + 196
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6a51ff62 sleep + 41
3   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff6a6b4d4b _waiting4memory + 14
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff6a69c344 _xpc_mach_port_allocate + 92
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff6a6a1c88 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply + 127
6   com.apple.spotlight.SpotlightDaemon 0x00007fff61c55583 __28-[CSSearchAgent startQuery:]_block_invoke.175 + 159
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a40c134 _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 83
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a40050e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a405ace _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 597
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a406485 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 414
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a407706 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 2034
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff6a40fa9e _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 598
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d71b _pthread_wqthread + 290
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d57b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 19:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 20:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6a65d56c start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
 rax: 0x00007fabb1fa6f20  rbx: 0x00007fabb1fa6f20  rcx: 0x00007fff6a6bd5b0  rdx: 0x00007fabb1fa6f20
 rdi: 0x00007fabe7914030  rsi: 0x00007fabb1f2e930  rbp: 0x0000700009a01720  rsp: 0x0000700009a01708
  r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000013  r10: 0x00007fabe7914dd8  r11: 0x0000000000000206
 r12: 0x0000000010002004  r13: 0x0000000000000001  r14: 0x00007fabe7914030  r15: 0x00007fabe7914030
 rip: 0x00007fff6a6ba615  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x00007fff9446ccc0

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000000
Trap Number:     6


Binary Images:
      0x103ed2000 -        0x103ee7ff7  corespotlightd (2074.4) <FE61B734-927B-3163-AF59-C62BE6CC4702> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Support/corespotlightd
      0x104730000 -        0x1047c0b5f  dyld (733.6) <DAFEA246-2F9A-3DCB-A37C-4246D4F92770> /usr/lib/dyld
   0x7fff2e8f0000 -     0x7fff2eae9ffd  com.apple.avfoundation (2.0 - 1730.15) <FC9245DB-747D-39BF-88DC-3B16FE040C19> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AVFoundation
   0x7fff2eaea000 -     0x7fff2ebb6ff8  com.apple.audio.AVFAudio (1.0 - ???) <6242C6F4-8B5C-3593-8250-A567D9B5B8C1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AVFAudio.framework/Versions/A/AVFAudio
   0x7fff2ecd6000 -     0x7fff2ecd6fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <71987428-FB54-3F6E-8699-DCC8BADC7D01> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
   0x7fff2ecee000 -     0x7fff2f595ff7  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - 524.2) <6857F772-73E8-348B-9976-3BA0E5570FAA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
   0x7fff2f596000 -     0x7fff2f72ffef  libBLAS.dylib (1303) <5DDE58FD-747B-34CA-81A2-7BCDFF3DD291> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
   0x7fff2f730000 -     0x7fff2f936fff  libBNNS.dylib (144.40.3) <8FBAAA82-90E2-3EDD-A96B-8D2139DCA619> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
   0x7fff2f938000 -     0x7fff2fcecfff  libLAPACK.dylib (1303) <7E61073B-DB96-3AE8-B188-5FBB20479A8C> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
   0x7fff2fced000 -     0x7fff2fd02ff8  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1303) <A5695D91-D87C-3E66-A470-16A166D8B43B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib


External Modification Summary:
 Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
   task_for_pid: 6
   thread_create: 0
   thread_set_state: 0
 Calls made by this process:
   task_for_pid: 0
   thread_create: 0
   thread_set_state: 0
 Calls made by all processes on this machine:
   task_for_pid: 2908
   thread_create: 0
   thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=734.4M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=734.4M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=2.0G written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=2.0G(100%)

                               VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        1 
CoreServices                      4608K        6 
Dispatch continuations            32.0M        1 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        1 
MALLOC                             2.0G     1373 
MALLOC guard page                   64K       16 
MALLOC_LARGE (reserved)           25.0M        5         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
Memory Tag 243                    12.0M        2 
Memory Tag 244                    4224K        6 
Memory Tag 246                    2048K        1 
Memory Tag 247                    1024K        1 
Memory Tag 250                      32K        1 
STACK GUARD                       56.1M       21 
Stack                             18.2M       21 
VM_ALLOCATE                          4K        1 
__DATA                            55.2M      517 
__DATA_CONST                       319K        5 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       353.0M        3 
__OBJC_RO                         32.0M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         1780K        2 
__TEXT                           381.4M      514 
__UNICODE                          564K        1 
mapped file                      235.2M       64 
shared memory                      596K        9 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              3.1G     2574 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     3.1G     2574 


System Profile:
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Boot Volume File System Type: apfs
Memory Module: BANK 0/ChannelA-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2667 MHz, Micron, 8ATF1G64HZ-2G6E1
Memory Module: BANK 2/ChannelB-DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR4, 2667 MHz, Micron, 8ATF1G64HZ-2G6E1
USB Device: USB 3.1 Bus
USB Device: Apple T2 Bus
USB Device: Composite Device
USB Device: Touch Bar Backlight
USB Device: Touch Bar Display
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: Headset
USB Device: Ambient Light Sensor
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Apple T2 Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 51.4
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 51.4
Model: MacBookPro16,1, BootROM 1037.40.127.0.0 (iBridge: 17.16.11583.0.0,0), 8 processors, 8-Core Intel Core i9, 2.3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 
Graphics: kHW_IntelUHDGraphics630Item, Intel UHD Graphics 630, spdisplays_builtin
Graphics: kHW_AMDRadeonPro5500MItem, AMD Radeon Pro 5500M, spdisplays_pcie_device, 4 GB
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x7BF), wl0: Oct 19 2019 15:38:45 version 9.113.2.0.32.5.39 FWID 01-c66dbfbd
Bluetooth: Version 7.0.1f1, 3 services, 25 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
```

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208659/apples-map-program-crashes-repeatedly-and-reliably-whenever-a-zoom-is-attempted This had Font Book in the issue, so just blaming the topmost process may not be helpful always.

Comment: You get free apple support with a new machine. give apple a call.

Comment: It’s a 2019 MBP. Was it brand new or “new to you?”  In other words was it an open box, refurb or even a customer return?  Just making 100% certain. If brand new and you haven’t installed anything yet, I wouldn’t even try to diagnose, I’d send it back!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the Google File Stream seems to be the cause of kernel panic.

[macOS Catalina watchdog timeout kernel panics](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390620/macos-catalina-watchdog-timeout-kernel-panics)